# Fill the rest of the height of container with another div and make it scroll horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am trying to force div #content to fill vertically #screen div which has fixed size and allows scrolling on horizontal axis. The problem is #header which fit its content so I am unable to set fixed height for #content. #content has columns which are horizontally scrollable.

[image: Screenshot]

Setting height in jQuery should be easy but I am looking for CSS-only solution.

```
#container {
    background: #f00;    
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    padding:10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#header {
    background: #0f0;    
    width: 100%;
}
#content {
    -webkit-column-width: 100px;
    max-width: none;
    height:100% ;/*can not set fixed number as #header height could change*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y7sfc/2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question fully but iI'm assuming its something along the lines of you not wanting a vertical scroll bar? and only a horizontal overflow right?

I added a `height: 20%;` to your header (or whatever you want) and changed the height of your `#content` to fill the rest so in this case, `height: 80%;`.

```
#container {
    background: #f00;    
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    padding:10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#header {
    background: #0f0;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;/*add up to 100%(total size) of #container along with other elements*/
}
#content {
    -webkit-column-width: 100px;
    max-width: none;
    height: 80%% ;/*add up to 100%(total size) of #container along with other elements*/
}
```

I believe the problem is because your `#header` and `#content` are both inside `#container` which has a set amount of space. Since your `#content` was set to take `heigh: 100%` of the space inside `#container` the `#header` still had to make room thus pushing the limit above 100% and creating a vertical slide bar.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y7sfc/4/

Comment: The problem is that header is dynamic and has to fit its content so I can not set percentage

Comment: Ahhh I see. I'm not sure then. But, I did some quick search and if you google "filling container 100 with dynamic elements" you'll get a lot of similar stackoverflow cases similar to yours. Major difference is the column width you requested. Best of luck